# boost vs POCO as for learning curve and suitability for beginners (HTTP client)

Tags: c++, boost, poco-libraries

which library would you advise me to use? I don't know any of these libraries.
I heard, that Boost is very often used but also it's hard to code in.

So to make this question as objective as possible:
Just simply from the aspect of beginner programmer (I've coded ~1000 LOC in C++ in my life)
which library would be better to learn?

I'll be using it mainly for HTTP client.

Comment: Boost is not an acronym, btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is bound to be subjective but with particular emphasis on *for a beginner* then I think POCO is clearly the way to go.  It actually has some HTTPClient classes and once you get beyond the point of being happy that something works the code is clear enough to follow so that you can dig in and understand *why* it works if that is where things lead you.

POCO is well written OOP code and does not require much in the way of understanding templates and such.  The classes are well integrated with one another, extensive, and the documentation more or less points you to the next (or previous) class that you need.  You won't be dashing around 20 separate libs as Boost is likely to have you doing.  (There is always time for that later!)

Comment: I've just downloaded the sources of POCO and I'm taking a look at the testsuit - and I must agreee - it is understandable :) thank you

Comment: @Tomy I never got the POCO library running with VS 2010 on a w7 64bit. What OS and code environment are you running?

Comment: @Rps woo-hoo! I did it! :-) It's simpler than one would think. Check out http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5342 and do the same thing (update PATH + update compier and linker properties...)

Comment: @Tomy: what is the path to be added, the libs to the project cppunit wright?

Comment: @Rps nope :). Imagine, your POCO is in E:\poco-1.4.3p1. The add: "E:\poco-1.4.3p1" and "E:\poco-1.4.3p1\bin"

Comment: @Tomy: and you are starting from the vs100 example?
Got an error: cannot execute  "../cppunitd.dll".
I also tried to build it again via the commandline in vs, but that didn't help :(

Comment: @Rps here - check this out. If it won't help I give in. http://blog.novellizator.cz/post/20473945893/how-to-set-up-poco-c-library-in-windows-7-pro-64bit